# How to apply Conditional Formatting based on previous cell value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is it possible apply Conditional formatting based on the value of a cell from the left?

What I need is to apply a red colour if the value is less then previous cell no colour if it unchanged and green if it is higher.

```
|  5   |   10  |  8  |   8   |
|      | green | red |       |
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is one of the more basic things with conditional formatting. Click `Conditional Formatting` on the `Home` tab, `Highlight Cells Rules`, `Greater Than` and either select a cell to compare it to or type the cell reference in. Repeat for less than.

---

It's a little more complicated to apply such a rule across a row/block.

I'll be using the first row as an example.

1. Select a block. The '[active cell](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-glossary-HA010218143.aspx)' is the white cell in the selection. This is important later.

   [[image: Screenshot of selected block]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOMxm.png)
2. Click `Conditional Formatting` on the `Home` tab, `Highlight Cells Rules`, `Greater Than`

   [[image: Screenshot of menu]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXiS9.png)
3. Select the cell you want to compare the active cell to. The other highlighted cells will automagically be compared to the cell shifted according to the [relative](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-HP010342940.aspx) position to the active cell. In this example, the selected cell is one column to the left of the active cell, so each cell in your selection will be compared to the cell one column to the left of the cell to be formatted. (I'm bad at explaining that, feel free to comment asking for clarification.)

   Select the desired colour.

   Make sure the formula has no dollar (`$`) signs. They mean it is an [absolute](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-HP010342940.aspx) reference, which means all cells in the selection will be compared to the specified cell, not the relative one "one column left". We don't want that, we want a relative reference instead, so remove the dollar signs.

   [[image: Screenshot of popup with options]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3N6Z.png)
4. Press OK.
5. Go back to step 2, but use `Less Than` this time.
6. There is no need to set a colour for "equal value", since default is blank. If you wish to set a different colour, there's an `Equal To` option too.

End result:

[[image: Screenshot of formatted cells]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eODZC.png)

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I needed!!!

Thanks.

Comment: this is not working in 2023 - all the cells in the block are comparing themselves to the same cell

Comment: @bshirley Did you make sure to remove any `$` as described in the second half of step 3? I've just tested and this still works as originally described - it will default to an absolute reference which is why you need to edit the formula to remove the absolute anchors and make it relative. This is no different from the behaviour back in 2012.

Answer (score 40):

This will be a cell reference of the cell to the left. Highlight the table and do conditional formatting (greater than, less than).

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1)
```

Comment: Why make it harder than it needs to be, when a correct answer has already been posted?

Comment: @Scott Just because one answer has been posted doesn't mean this one isn't any less valid.

Comment: @Chipperyman: I know; but this answer is unnecessarily complicated, has no particular advantage (or at least none that is stated), and it doesn't provide the level of detail that the OP probably needs.

Comment: Then don't use this solution. It's always nice to have alternatives, even if they're bad.

Comment: I added this answer because it gives you a formula you can use outside of the conditional formatting. Useful for all sorts of things. Sorry I didn't take screen shots, really didn't think they were necessary.

Comment: @Scott +1. Here is a great use case for this - imagine having to compare multiple columns of the table, highlighting those that are bigger than their left neighbors. This can get pasted as a format and work out of the box, none of the other ones will.

Comment: Should be the accepted solution.

Comment: @dre, awesome answer, thank God you posted this (which really, should be the accepted solution as it can be applied to a massive range of rows in no time).@Scott, image that you've got 300 columns rather than just 3 like in the example, how would you do that with what you call the 'correct' answer?

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you @dre. Quick concept question: I'm using this to format all the cells in column A (starting with A2) that have values identical to the cell directly above them...
`A2=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),-1,0)`
It works, however, I had to use this because when I initially tried `A2=A1`, instead of formatting all cells but the first in a set of duplicates, it formatted all cells but the LAST in the set. Anyone know why that is? By my logic, `A2=A1` should compare a cell to the cell above it, but in practice it appeared to compare it to the cell below it. Why?

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me. The others don't seem to propagate down the column properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in Google Spreadsheets, this will work with the following config:

[image: Conditional format rules]